# Python MySQL module

Tags: python, mysql, module

I'm developing a web application that needs to interface with a MySQL database, and I can't seem to find any really good modules out there for Python.

I'm specifically looking for fast module, capable of handling hundreds of thousands of connections (and queries, all within a short period of time of each other), without an significant impact on the speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) is pretty much the only game in town for python mysql access.

Answer (score 10):

I think my answer will be an update to the game field.

There is now the official MysQL Python Connector.

Install:

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Or download it from here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-python.html

Answer (score 2):

I usually use [SQLObject](http://www.sqlobject.org/), but I haven't used it under highly stressful conditions, so I couldn't vouch for performance (having said that, I wouldn't speak *against* it).

To copy some demo code from another answer:

```
from sqlobject import *

# Replace this with the URI for your actual database
connection = connectionForURI('mysql://server:XXXX')
sqlhub.processConnection = connection

# This defines the columns for your database table. See SQLObject docs for how it
# does its conversions for class attributes <-> database columns (underscores to camel
# case, generally)

class Song(SQLObject):

    name = StringCol()
    artist = StringCol()
    album = StringCol()

# Create fake data for demo - this is not needed for the real thing
def MakeFakeDB():
    Song.createTable()
    s1 = Song(name="B Song",
              artist="Artist1",
              album="Album1")
    s2 = Song(name="A Song",
              artist="Artist2",
              album="Album2")

def Main():
    # This is an iterable, not a list
    all_songs = Song.select().orderBy(Song.q.name)

    # Do something by iterating over the song list...
```

Answer (score 1):

[oursql](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oursql/0.9.2) is another option for python-mysql access.  It is a much more complete wrapper of libmysqlclient than MySQLdb.  Tends to be faster in my experience with lots of nice additional features.