# Referencing/manipulating SQL fields in Python code

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to code a website similar to reddit where people can post stories and then vote on them

So right now, I have some Python code to create a time score (PostDate) and a general rating score (VoteStatus), however I need to know how to reference/manipulate fields in an SQL table with Python.

Any help?

```
    import datetime

    def PostDate(PostID):
        dday = datetime.fromtimestamp(#I need a way to reference the timestamp
                     #field of a specifc PostID entry in each of these blank parens).day
        mmonth = datetime.fromtimestamp().month
        yyear = datetime.fromtimestamp().year
        hhour = datetime.fromtimestamp().hour
        mminute = datetime.fromtimestamp().minute
        ssecond = datetime.fromtimestamp().second
        return ((dday * 1000000) + (mmonth * 100000000) + (yyear * 10000000000) + (hhour * 10000) + (mminute * 100) + ssecond)

    def VoteStatus(PostID):
        TimeScore = PostDate(Post)
        cday = datetime.now.day
        cmonth = datetime.now.month
        cyear = datetime.now.year
        chour = datetime.now.hour
        cminute = datetime.now.minute
        csecond = datetime.now.second
        Now = ((cday * 1000000) + (cmonth * 100000000) + (cyear * 10000000000) + (chour * 10000) + (cminute * 100) + csecond)
        timestatus = (Now - TimeScore)
        votes = #Reference the value given in the total votes field in the SQL table
        return (.45 * timestatus) + (.55 * votes)






    SELECT * FROM Database ORDER BY VoteStatus
```

Comment: What do you mean by reference/manipulate?  Do you mean update existing records?

Comment: So when a user submits a story, their post is timestamped automatically in a field in the SQL table. I want my python code to reference that timestamp in PostDate to create a score in VoteStatus. The value VoteStatus will be calculated for each post and then be inputted as a value in the table for each post - which a new table will then be sorted by.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, see this question: [Python MySQL module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644839/python-mysql-module)

There is also an `sqlite3` module that you can use on a flat sqlite file, like so:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
rows = list(conn.execute("SELECT * FROM Database ORDER BY VoteStatus"))
```